# Wireless network lagging on HP laptop

Tags: networking

I have a HP Pavilion 15-ab217ng notebook (https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04908430)
and I'm using **Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS**.

Since the latest update (a couple of days ago) I have been experiencing very slow network traffic for some reason.

The symptoms are:

- When I start a ping (some web server) in bash after I login I get `Temporary failure in name resolution`.
- After a couple of minutes the ping starts working and the times are around 10 ms which is reasonable.
- But when I start Thunderbird and want to check my e-mails I get `Failed to connect to server` and `Connection timed out` error messages.
- When I open Firefox and want to surf the web it takes 10 seconds for a page to load and sometimes it fails showing `Server Not Found` or `Secure Connection Failed` error messages as well. Or it does load the page but doesn't load any/some images on the page.

WLAN signal strength is excellent and reconnecting doesn't fix the problem.

Edit: I did an internet speed test and this is the result:

- 39.56 Mbps download
- 21.26 Mbps upload

Which is normal.

The content of `/var/log/apt/history.log` is this:

```
Start-Date: 2022-12-05  20:55:24
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: krisztian (1000)
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-132.148, 5.4.0-135.152), libfprint-2-2:amd64 (1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.9, 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.10), snapd:amd64 (2.57.5+20.04, 2.57.5+20.04ubuntu0.1), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.11.3~20.04.1, 27.12~20.04.1), dnsmasq-base:amd64 (2.80-1.1ubuntu1.5, 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.6), passwd:amd64 (1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04.2, 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04.4), apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.24, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.25), libtiff5:amd64 (4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.6, 4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.7), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.24, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.25), lintian:amd64 (2.62.0ubuntu2.1, 2.62.0ubuntu2.2), login:amd64 (1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04.2, 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04.4), libmysqlclient21:amd64 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.24, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.25), libxml2:amd64 (2.9.10+dfsg-5ubuntu0.20.04.4, 2.9.10+dfsg-5ubuntu0.20.04.5), ca-certificates:amd64 (20211016~20.04.1, 20211016ubuntu0.20.04.1), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187.34, 1.187.35), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.24, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.25), xdg-desktop-portal:amd64 (1.6.0-1ubuntu1, 1.6.0-1ubuntu2)
End-Date: 2022-12-05  20:56:55

Start-Date: 2022-12-05  21:43:02
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.283'
Install: linux-image-5.4.0-135-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-135.152, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-135:amd64 (5.4.0-135.152, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-135-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-135.152, automatic), linux-modules-5.4.0-135-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-135.152, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-135-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-135.152, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.132.132, 5.4.0.135.133), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.132.132, 5.4.0.135.133), linux-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.132.132, 5.4.0.135.133)
End-Date: 2022-12-05  21:45:09

Start-Date: 2022-12-05  21:45:31
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.283'
Remove: linux-image-5.4.0-132-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-132.148), linux-headers-5.4.0-132:amd64 (5.4.0-132.148), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-132-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-132.148), linux-modules-5.4.0-132-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-132.148), linux-headers-5.4.0-132-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-132.148)
End-Date: 2022-12-05  21:45:43

Start-Date: 2022-12-13  22:03:24
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: krisztian (1000)
Upgrade: libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1, 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2), libwind0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1, 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2), binutils-dev:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.3, 2.34-6ubuntu1.4), libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.6), libctf-nobfd0:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.3, 2.34-6ubuntu1.4), libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1, 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.2), libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1, 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2), binutils:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.3, 2.34-6ubuntu1.4), python3-pil:amd64 (7.0.0-4ubuntu0.6, 7.0.0-4ubuntu0.7), libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1, 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2), libpython3.8:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.6), python3.8:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.6), samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1, 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.2), binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.3, 2.34-6ubuntu1.4), python3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.6), libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1, 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2), libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1, 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.2), binutils-common:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.3, 2.34-6ubuntu1.4), libbinutils:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.3, 2.34-6ubuntu1.4), libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.6), libroken18-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1, 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2), libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1, 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2), libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1, 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2), libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1, 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2), libctf0:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.3, 2.34-6ubuntu1.4), tzdata:amd64 (2022f-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2022g-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-12-13  22:03:41

Start-Date: 2022-12-19  18:14:21
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.112'
Upgrade: xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4, 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4, 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4, 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4, 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5), firefox-locale-de:amd64 (107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xwayland:amd64 (2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4, 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5), python3-tz:amd64 (2019.3-1, 2019.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.0), firefox:amd64 (107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-12-19  18:14:37
```

The last lines of `/var/log/dpkg.log` are:

```
2022-12-19 18:14:21 startup archives unpack
2022-12-19 18:14:22 upgrade firefox:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:22 status half-configured firefox:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:22 status unpacked firefox:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:22 status half-installed firefox:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status triggers-pending gnome-menus:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status triggers-pending desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.24-1ubuntu3
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status triggers-pending mime-support:all 3.64ubuntu1
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status triggers-pending bamfdaemon:amd64 0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu2
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status triggers-pending hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status unpacked firefox:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:31 upgrade firefox-locale-de:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status half-configured firefox-locale-de:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status unpacked firefox-locale-de:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status half-installed firefox-locale-de:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:31 status unpacked firefox-locale-de:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:32 upgrade firefox-locale-en:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status half-configured firefox-locale-en:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status unpacked firefox-locale-en:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status half-installed firefox-locale-en:amd64 107.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status unpacked firefox-locale-en:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:32 upgrade python3-tz:all 2019.3-1 2019.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.0
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status half-configured python3-tz:all 2019.3-1
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status unpacked python3-tz:all 2019.3-1
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status half-installed python3-tz:all 2019.3-1
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status unpacked python3-tz:all 2019.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.0
2022-12-19 18:14:32 upgrade xserver-common:all 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status half-configured xserver-common:all 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status unpacked xserver-common:all 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status half-installed xserver-common:all 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status unpacked xserver-common:all 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:32 upgrade xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:32 status half-configured xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status unpacked xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status half-installed xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status unpacked xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:33 upgrade xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status half-configured xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status unpacked xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status half-installed xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status unpacked xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:33 upgrade xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status half-configured xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status unpacked xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status half-installed xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status unpacked xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:33 upgrade xwayland:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status half-configured xwayland:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status unpacked xwayland:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:33 status half-installed xwayland:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.4
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status unpacked xwayland:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:34 startup packages configure
2022-12-19 18:14:34 configure firefox:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status unpacked firefox:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status half-configured firefox:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status installed firefox:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:34 configure python3-tz:all 2019.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.0 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status unpacked python3-tz:all 2019.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.0
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status half-configured python3-tz:all 2019.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.0
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status installed python3-tz:all 2019.3-1ubuntu0.20.04.0
2022-12-19 18:14:34 configure firefox-locale-en:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status unpacked firefox-locale-en:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status half-configured firefox-locale-en:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status installed firefox-locale-en:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:34 configure xserver-common:all 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status unpacked xserver-common:all 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status half-configured xserver-common:all 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status installed xserver-common:all 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:34 configure xwayland:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status unpacked xwayland:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status half-configured xwayland:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status installed xwayland:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:34 configure firefox-locale-de:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status unpacked firefox-locale-de:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status half-configured firefox-locale-de:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status installed firefox-locale-de:amd64 108.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-12-19 18:14:34 configure xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status unpacked xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:34 status half-configured xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status installed xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:36 configure xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status unpacked xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status half-configured xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status installed xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:36 configure xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status unpacked xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status half-configured xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status installed xserver-xephyr:amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.5
2022-12-19 18:14:36 trigproc desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.24-1ubuntu3 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status half-configured desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.24-1ubuntu3
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.24-1ubuntu3
2022-12-19 18:14:36 trigproc mime-support:all 3.64ubuntu1 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status half-configured mime-support:all 3.64ubuntu1
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status installed mime-support:all 3.64ubuntu1
2022-12-19 18:14:36 trigproc hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status half-configured hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2022-12-19 18:14:36 trigproc gnome-menus:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status half-configured gnome-menus:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
2022-12-19 18:14:36 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:36 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1
2022-12-19 18:14:37 status installed man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1
2022-12-19 18:14:37 trigproc bamfdaemon:amd64 0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu2 <none>
2022-12-19 18:14:37 status half-configured bamfdaemon:amd64 0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu2
2022-12-19 18:14:37 status installed bamfdaemon:amd64 0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu2
```

**Update**: I got myself an external WLAN stick and using that I have no problems with the wireless connection. So the problem has something to do with the driver of the integrated WLAN device within the laptop. It can't be a hardware problem because the issue is not there when I boot Windows 10.

I've read that the wireless devices in HP laptops generally have problems under Ubuntu. :-(

How could this be fixed?

Comment: "Latest update" is too vague to offer useful advice. Please review your `/var/log/apt/history.log` and specify the relevant packages. Keep in mind that an update might be coincidental -- you problem might be unrelated after all, so it might be more productive to start with network troubleshooting instead of chasing updates.

Comment: If this is due to update, please, check /var/log/dpkg.log

Comment: @user535733 I added the content of the said files to the original post above. Yes, I think that it makes sense to troubleshoot the networking instead of the updates, however I don't really know how to go about it. I might as well update to the latest Ubuntu release and hope for the problem to be fixed.

Comment: Your assertion that your network problem was caused by a recent update does not seem supported by your logs. Consider removing that element from your question; it is a distraction. Use the search box at the top of this page to look for previous network troubleshooting questions. Also, show actual ping input/output in your question rather than summarizing -- details matter.

Comment: @user535733 I guess I celebrated too early. The problem is back again. I think it must have something to do with the wireless driver. Wired LAN connection works outstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accident I found the cause of this issue. For some reason I had a manual DNS server configuration in my network settings. On Ubuntu 22.04 this can be seen here:

- Left click on the "Network" icon in the status bar on the top right
- In the drop down menu select "Edit Connections..." (last entry on my system)
- Select your network and click on the "Settings" wheel icon (bottom left in window)
- Navigate to the "IPv4 Settings" tab
- Check that the field "Additional DNS Servers" is empty